# Can drill replace reciprocal saw?

Tags: metal, metal-cutting

I need to cut some metal fence, and I don't have a reciprocal saw. I've included a picture of the fence to give you an idea of its thickness. Essentially, I'll be cutting the rail off the post. The area where I want to cut is approximately 1"x2".

Is there something for the drill that can replace the reciprocal saw for this type of job?

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: A cut off disk for a drill would work but take a long time. If you have a skill saw a metal cutting disk or blade will cut it in a few minutes. I would use a 4" angle grinder and cut the weld since you want it flat.

Comment: What is this railing part of? From the looks of the picture you are up at about the 3rd story.

Answer (score 3):

No, there isn't really a drill accessory made that will make that job easy. I wouldn't bother with any cutoff or grinder wheel. It would take a very long time and would chatter and bounce around a lot.

Beg or borrow an electric saw, or use an abrasive circular saw blade, or use a basic hacksaw. You'll probably want an angle grinder to flatten the cut, and you could actually use the grinder to make the cut.

The long and the short of it is that a drill isn't your huckleberry.

Comment: Can you send me an example of a disc I could use with an angle grinder that would easily cut this? Thanks.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=angle+grinder+steel+cutting+disc&rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS738US738&oq=angle+grinder+steel&aqs=chrome.0.0j69i57j0l4.3808j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Answer (score 0):

it's not a drill accessory either, but don't discount the value of a sharp (new) hacksaw blade in a well-tensioned saw.

Use lubricating oil of just about any sort and push the saw into the material to be cut. Lift the saw on the back stroke, to prevent contact with the material which will quickly dull the blade.

If you have no obstacles on the back side of the rail, you can cut that entire portion in a few minutes.

Comment: Would any blade work for this job, or would I need to buy a specific blade? Thanks.

Comment: A quality hacksaw blade would be labeled as bi-metal or similar. Very hard steel for the teeth bonded to a less brittle steel body.